# Not able to receive POST request Data in PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am Sending data to Phantom from Nodejs Server using Request Module. Here is the Request

```
Request.post({
  "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
   "url": "http://localhost:8089",
   "body": JSON.stringify(data),
}, (error, response, body) => {
if(error) {
    return console.dir(error);
}
```

I want to retrieve post Data and I am getting request.post = undefined in Phantom JS. Here is the Sample Code :

```
server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
if (request.method == 'POST') {
   console.log(request.post); //Returning Undefined
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran a test with `request` v2.87.0 and `PhantomJS` v2.1.1:

**Node.js**

```
var request = require("request");

var data = { "some" : "value" };

request.post({

        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)

    }, function(){ process.exit() });
```

**PhantomJS**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var server = require('webserver').create();

server.listen("127.0.0.1:9999", function (request, response) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.post));

    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.write("OK");
    response.close();    

});
```

This produces the following result:

> "{\"some\":\"value\"}"

Even if no body is sent, empty string is logged. So we can conclude that either way `request.post` is not `undefined`. Please make sure that you are using the latest version of `request` and `PhantomJS`